# Evaluate rules against a multimap using MVEL

Tags: multimap, mvel

Just wondering how can I evaluate rules against a multimap using MVEL.

I.e:

```
rule-> "foo" == "200"
```

Possible values of `foo` in the context `[100, 200, 300]`.

I don't know which are going to be the possible values so I can't include them as part of the rule.

Ideally I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
valueList.add("100");
valueList.add("200");

List<String> otherList = new ArrayList<String>();
otherList.add("otherValue");

Map<String, List<String>> context = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
context.put("foo", valueList);
context.put("other", otherList);

MVEL.eval("foo == 200", context)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should tag this question with the rules-engine framework that you are using so that it will have more likelihood of being answered by someone that specializes in the particular application of MVEL that you are concerned with.

Comment: you should consider using guava's multimap classes http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the plain java code as well.
We have tried this and it executes fine. u can just pass your java code to Mvel and it will give you the result.

Function can be appended to string at run time. Just create a rule/condition with your logic. The bold part is what we write.

```
public Boolean evaluate(Map contextMap){

   **ClassA A = (ClassA) contextMap.get("contextObjectClassA");
    List<ClassB> classb = A.getclassb();
            if(null!=classb  && classb .size()>0){
                    return true;
                }else{
                return false;
            }**
    }
```